# django-taggit on models with UUID as pk throwing out of range on save

Tags: django, django-taggit, django-contenttypes

I have models that uses UUID as its PK

```
class Foo(models.Model):        
    foo_id = models.UUIDField(  
        primary_key=True,             
        default=uuid.uuid4,           
        editable=False                
    )  
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

When I go and try to add a new tag

```
f = Foo.objects.latest('pk')
f.tags.add("testing")
```

I get `DataError: integer out of range`

When I import pdb on the cursor to view the SQL going in I see this.

```
(Pdb) params                                                                                                              
(1, 287082253891563438098836942573405313042, 9)                                                                           
(Pdb) sql                                                                                                                 
'INSERT INTO "taggit_taggeditem" ("tag_id", "object_id", "content_type_id") VALUES (%s, %s, %s) RETURNING "taggit_taggedit
m"."id"'
```

That long integer (`287082253891563438098836942573405313042`) trying to be insterted is obvsiouly the cause for the error. This number is the int of the `UUID` for `foo_id`

```
In [6]: foo.foo_id.int                      
Out[6]: 287082253891563438098836942573405313042
```

Is there something I can set to allow `django-taggit` to play nicely with `contenttypes` and `UUID`?

Comment: I ended up forking a copy of taggit and modifying the Model to use a UUID so it would be compatible with my UUID field. Note you need to change the migration file as well before syncing your DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer based on Austin's comment.

In `django-taggit`, references to tagged models are stored in a model named `GenericTaggedItemBase` under a field called `object_id`. The `object_id` field is hardcoded to `models.IntegerField`. So it's not possible to tag models having UUID primary keys. The code is [located here](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/develop/taggit/models.py).

If all your models that need to be tagged are of the same type (in this case, `models.UUIDField`), then you can set `object_id`'s type to `models.UUIDField`.

Here are the changes that have to be made, assuming you're using `virtualenvwrapper`

1. Locate the `taggit` package in the site packages folder. `~/virtualenvs/<your_virtualenv>/lib/<python_version>/site-packages/taggit`
2. Copy the `taggit` directory into your project.
3. Delete the `taggit` directory from `site-packages`
4. In the `models.py` file in `taggit`, replace

`object_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Object id'), db_index=True)` with

```
object_id = models.UUIDField(verbose_name=_('Object id'), db_index=True)
```

5. Migrate taggit.

`python manage.py makemigrations taggit`

`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: When copying the taggit package into my own directory I just updated the migration rather then running makemigrations. They either need to be updated or removed then make migrations

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to extend @Pramod response, that was very helpful for me to find the right answer:

**Taggit** has another class that allows to change the behavior of the `TaggedItem`

Here is a snippet of how to implement this solution:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from taggit.models import GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase

class UUIDTaggedItem(GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):
    # If you only inherit GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, you need to define
    # a tag field. e.g.
    # tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name="uuid_tagged_items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")

class Food(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # ... fields here

    tags = TaggableManager(through=UUIDTaggedItem)
```

source: http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html#genericuuidtaggeditembase